# Where can I obtain activity logs of what AWS users have done

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I am fairly new to AWS, totally new to IAM. I've set up some user accounts and groups.

What I haven't seen yet is a log of user actions. If an EC2 instance gets created, rebooted, stopped, or deleted from the console, I'd like to know which user issued that command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for AWS CloudTrail:

> AWS CloudTrail is a service that enables governance, compliance,
>   operational auditing, and risk auditing of your AWS account. With
>   CloudTrail, you can log, continuously monitor, and retain account
>   activity related to actions across your AWS infrastructure. CloudTrail
>   provides event history of your AWS account activity, including actions
>   taken through the AWS Management Console, AWS SDKs, command line
>   tools, and other AWS services. This event history simplifies security
>   analysis, resource change tracking, and troubleshooting.
>
> AWS CloudTrail increases visibility into your user and resource
>   activity by recording AWS Management Console actions and API calls.
>   You can identify which users and accounts called AWS, the source IP
>   address from which the calls were made, and when the calls occurred.

https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/